# How to call a Query string from a Form

Tags: html, forms

I have a form that looks like this:

```html
<form action="<?=getScriptUrl()?>?page=Confirm">
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="email" placeholder="Email adress" required name="Email"></p>
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="text" placeholder="Message subject" required name="Subject">
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="text" placeholder="Message body" required name="Body">
      <p><button class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-padding-large" type="submit" id = "submit-form">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
        SEND TO ME
        </button>
    </form>
```

how do i create the query string ?page=confirm without sending the form data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function to create a new query string.

```
const createQueryStringParameter = (uri, key, value) => {
  const regex = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  const separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(regex)) return uri.replace(regex, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  else return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
}
```

Usage:

```
createQueryStringParameter("localhost:8000","page","confirm"); //"localhost:8000?page=confirm"
```

Comment: Yes, this worked exactly, thanks. I also needed to use ```<base target ="_blank">```